# Gnuplot: How can I change the y axis so there are not too large jumps in data

Tags: gnuplot, scale

as you can see below the yaxis has a large gap between 0 and 6*10^5...
is there a way to fix that? There should also be data below zero but the scale doesn't show it.

The plot I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `yrange` by

```
set yrange [0:100]
```

OR

```
set yrange [0:]
```

OR during the plot

```
plot[][0:] 'valami.dat'
```

etc...

**EDIT**

If you want to do it automatic, you can do:

```
stat 'valami.dat'
plot[][STATS_y_min:] 'valami.dat'
```

OR

```
plot 'valami.dat'
plot[][GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN:] 'valami.dat'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still it doesn't help in my case... I thought more about a way to set a scale (like showing each 1x10 step)